# Visitor Name in Einstein Bot welcome dialog

Tags: servicecloud, einstein-chatbot, service, einstein-bots, slack

Hi I'm working with einstein bot for user to be able to chat to the bot thru slack, without any pre-chat form, user can just type anything and bot will response with welcome dialog. I'm trying to make a welcome dialog with visitor name being mentioned. e.g

> 'Welcome [Visitor Name], Thank you for reaching out to helpdesk, how
> can I help you?'

I followed this guidance to put visitorName. But I couldn`t find this visitorName anywhere. And the visitor name populated on LiveChatTranscript record is auto number, not the visitor name.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_request_bodies.htm#ChasitorInit

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. By creating new custom field on LiveChatTranscript to store the visitor name, and from slack, when sending the JSON to salesforce, add the field in PrechatDetails.

> {
> “organizationId”: “”,
> “deploymentId”: “”,
> “buttonId”: “”,
> “AgentId”: “”,
> “sessionId”: “b274f2fa-66e4-4b9c-9bc2",
> “userAgent”: “”,
> “language”: “en-US”,
> “visitorName”: “Florent”,
> “prechatDetails”: [
> {
> “label”: “Visitor Name”,
> “value”: “Florent”,
> “displayToAgent”: true,
> “transcriptFields”: [
> “Visitor_Name__c”
> ],
> “entityFieldMaps”: []
> }
> ],
> “prechatEntities”: [],
> “receiveQueueUpdates”: true,
> “isPost”: true
> }

And then create an action in einstein bot to call flow/apex and query for the liveChatTranscript using {!$Context.RoutableId}. e.g:

> SELECT Id, Visitor_Name__c FROM LiveChatTranscript WHERE Id = RoutableId